# error does not load position styles when showing cdk overlay in leaflet in a position in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, leaflet, angular-cdk

I'm trying to put a "contextMenu" in angular leaflet, when done in an empty div it works. Image 01
[Image 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQb0D.png)
But when it tried to place over the leaflet, it doesn't load the position or overlay styles.
[Image 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrTy5.png)
[Imagen html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgRCI.png)
And when I activate the button toolpit, it just loads the overlay styles
[Image 03](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCwIp.png)
[Imagen html load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uw3Da.png)
CODE:

```
const openPan = (val) => this.open(val); 
this.map.addEventListener('contextmenu' , openPan);

open($event){  
  this.closePanel();
  const positionStrategy = this.overlay.position()
  .flexibleConnectedTo($event.containerPoint)
  .withPositions([
    {
      originX: 'end',
      originY: 'bottom',
      overlayX: 'end',
      overlayY: 'top',
    }
    ]);
    this.overlayRef = this.overlay.create({
      positionStrategy,
      scrollStrategy: this.overlay.scrollStrategies.close(),
      disposeOnNavigation: true
    },
    );
    this.overlayRef.attach(new TemplatePortal(this.userMenu, this.viewContainerRef));
    

  this.sub = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(document, 'click')
    .pipe(
      filter(event => {
        const clickTarget = event.target as HTMLElement;
        return !!this.overlayRef && !this.overlayRef.overlayElement.contains(clickTarget);
      }),
      take(1)
    ).subscribe(() => this.closePanel());
}
```

html

```
<div
  class="map"
  leaflet
  [leafletOptions]="options"
  (leafletDrawStart)="onDrawStart($event)"
  (contextmenu)=" $event. preventDefault();"
  (leafletMapZoom)="eventZoom($event)"
  (leafletMapReady)="onMapReady($event)"
>
</div>
<ng-template #userMenu   cdkConnectedOverlay> 
  <section class="user-menu">
      
      <div>Option 1 </div>


  </section>
</ng-template>
```

How can I solve that?